# Knockout + JQuery UI Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, knockout.js, jquery-autocomplete

I am trying to extend the JQUERY UI Autocomplete widget with knockout binding.

What I am trying to do is.

```
<input ccid="N1" controltype="MESAutoComplete" data-bind="MESAutoComplete: { dataTextField: 'FruitName', data:N1.CustomItems, value: N1.Value, search: search, enable: N1.Enable }" /></div>
```

At runtime I will get the above input element and assign

```
$.widget("custom.skeltacomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {    
_renderItem: function (ul, item)
{
    var t = '',
        result = '';

    $.each(this.options.columns, function (index, column)
    {
        t += '<span style="padding:0 4px;float:left;width:' + column.width + ';">' + item[column.valueField ? column.valueField : index] + '</span>'
    });

    result = $('<li></li>').data('item.autocomplete', item).append('<a class="mcacAnchor">' + t + '<div style="clear: both;"></div></a>').appendTo(ul);
    return result;
},
enableMonitor: '.theEnableMonitor'    
});
```

After this step.

```
$(element).skeltacomplete(
           {
               showHeader: true,
               columns: [{
                   name: 'ID',
                   width: '150px',
                   valueField: 'FruitId'
               },
               {
                   name: 'Name',
                   width: '120px',
                   valueField: 'FruitName'
               },
               {
                   name: 'Type',
                   width: '120px',
                   valueField: 'FruitType'
               }],

               // Event handler for when a list item is selected.
               select: function (event, ul)
               {
                   alert("sss = " + ul.item + " and items = " + ul.items);
                   this.value = (ul.item ? ul.item.FruitName : '');
                   return false;
               },

               // The rest of the options are for configuring the ajax webservice call.
               minLength: 1,
               source: function (request, response)
               {


var data = [{ "FruitId": "1", "FruitName": "apple", "FruitType": "Veg" }, { "FruitId": "2", "FruitName": "orange", "FruitType": "fruit" }];                       var   controlData = jQuery.grep(data, function (eachArrayItem)
                   {
                       return eachArrayItem[“FruitName”].indexOf(request.term) > -1;
                   });

                   response(controlData);
               }                 
           }
           );
```

**Now my question is**
I want to have custom function on the widget say myEnable: ‘IDontKnowFunction()’
Whenever the enable or value changes in the view model, I want to hook to the above function or corresponding function of the widget which will make the widget enable/disable.

Please advice. An example would be of great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution on my own.

```
enabled: function (propValue, element)
               {
                   if (!propValue)
                   {
                       $(element).Skeltacomplete("disable");
                       $(element).attr("disabled", true);
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       $(element).Skeltacomplete("enable");
                       $(element).attr("disabled", false);
                   }
               },
```

I added the above code to

> $(element).skeltacomplete(
>              {}

from the computed function, if the observable (enable) has updated then I trigger the function anonymously. 
it currently works for ReadOnly, Enable and Value which was my requirement.

Thanks for your help.